# Find informations about a place

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia

I'm tring to find informations about a place (ex : New York http://dbpedia.org/page/New_York). I' try to get informations suchs as nearestCity , museum)...
My request returns nothing...

```
String name = "New_York";
String s4 = "PREFIX  g:    <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>\n" +
            "PREFIX  rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>\n" +
            "PREFIX  onto: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>\n" +
            "PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>\n"+
            "PREFIX dp: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>\n"+
            "PREFIX dbprop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>\n" +
            "PREFIX grs: <http://www.georss.org/georss/>\n"+
            "PREFIX dbpedia-oll: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> \n"+
            "PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>PREFIX category: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:>\n"+
            "\n" +
            "SELECT ?nearestCity \n" +

            "WHERE\n" +
            "{ OPTIONAL{onto:"+name+" grs:nearestCity ?nearestCity .}\n"+
    "  }\n" +
            "LIMIT   300\n" +
            "";
```

Comment: Please post the real SPARQL query, not the Java String concatenation.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple problems with the query you are doing:

1) Some namespaces are wrong: the **resource** New_York has the URI: http://dbpedia.org/resource/New_York. In your query that would translate to `"dbpedia:"+name` instead of `"onto:"+name`.

2) The properties that you are looking for point to the resource New_York, not the other way around. For example, for the nearest city one, this is the query that works (note the namespaces again for the property):

```
SELECT  ?nearestCity where {
?nearestCity <http://dbpedia.org/property/nearestCity>  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/New_York>.
}LIMIT  300
```

(See [results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20%20%3Fm%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%3Fm%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FnearestCity%3E%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FNew_York%3E.%0D%0A%7DLIMIT%20%20300&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on))

And for museum:

```
SELECT  ?m where {
    ?m <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/museum>  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/New_York>.
    }LIMIT  300
```

(See [results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20%20%3Fm%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%3Fm%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2Fmuseum%3E%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FNew_York%3E.%0D%0A%7DLIMIT%20%20300&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on))